# Is there a way to read a password protected excel file using python?

Tags: python, spyder

Is there a way to read a password protected excel file using python? i tried using win32com but it required me to manually key in the password in the cmd

Comment: You probably want to look into `openpyxl` and read this https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protection.html

Comment: Also, to get better help (or any at all) on StackOverflow, please try solving a problem yourself and share your solution to ask about problems with it. Don't post open questions like these - they are likely to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

From a past answer

Workbooks.Open might do it
Syntax is something like xlwb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename, False, True, None, password)
documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx

Comment: I tried using this method and it prompt me to enter the password afterwards